# How to plot bar for 3 series with multiple samples

Tags: r, ggplot2, series

My question is how to plot a bar graphic to compare 3 variables where I have a set of samples. Suppose the variables are temperatures and so, I can have the following data frame

```
    T1     T2     T3
    1.04   0.72   0.74
    0.23   0.32   0.55
    0.78   0.40   1.22
    220    210    213
    1.3    0.9    1.2
```

And I want to get something like this picture (I tried change a sample graphic to try explain what I need):

[image]

The idea is to have 3 bar plotted for each sample line.
I tried to use `ggplot` but had no success trying to generate the graphic. Maybe I need to rearrange the samples in groups or something similar.
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

`ggplot` is setup to work with data in long format.  You can reshape it in various ways, here using `reshape2` (your data called `dat`)

```
## Reshape the data
library(reshape2)
dat <- melt(dat)

ggplot(dat, aes(value, fill=variable)) +
  geom_bar(position=position_dodge())
```

Comment: Hey nongkrong, thanks for your replay. The melt function is the TIP to find out the correct graphic. I had to add some points to your answer and the final answer was the following:
     `dat <- melt(dat, id="X")`

     `ggplot(dat, aes(X, fill=variable)) + geom_bar(position=position_dodge(), stat="identity")`